# Flutter/Dart/Firebase - wait until data has loaded before displaying

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a list of unique "events" in my app. I have created a couple of functions to extract the data from firebase:

```
  // event list from snapshot
  List<String> _eventsFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.docs.map(
      (doc) {
        return doc['event'].toString() ?? '';
      },
    ).toList();
  }

  //get events data
  Stream<List<String>> get events {
    return productCollection.snapshots().map(_eventsFromSnapshot);
}
```

I then want to build my list view in another screen. I have implemented my StreamProvider in the root page of my homescreen:

```
  class OurHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OurHomePageState createState() => _OurHomePageState();
}

    class _OurHomePageState extends State<OurHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamProvider<List<Product>>.value(
          value: OurDatabase().products.handleError((e) {
            print(e.toString());
          }),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    OurHeadline(),
                    AllCards(),
                    HowItWorks(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And then I create a function to return the list of Strings and use that in my stateless widget:

```
    class AllCards extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> uniqueEventList = getListOfEvents(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [Text('Browse all Cards'), Text('Shop All')],
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 125,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: uniqueEventList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(),
                    ),
                    width: 160.0,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(uniqueEventList[i]),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<String> getListOfEvents(BuildContext context) {
    final uniqueEvents = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context);
    final List<String> list = [];
    for (var item in uniqueEvents) {
      list.add(item.event);
    }
    return list.toSet().toList();
  }
}
```

The problem is that whenever I switch pages, for a split second I get this message and an error appears:

```
The getter 'iterator' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: iterator
```

Which indicates to me that I need to use some sort of async functionality to wait for the events data to finish loading, but is there a simple way to do this without going for something like a Future builder?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You'll want to look at `StreamBuilder` for this. That widget checks the state of the underlying stream, and uses that to render (or not render) the different states of the data in your widget treee.

Comment: If you're going this route, I'd suggest not rebuilding your UI directly based on events. Use events to trigger changes in your state and then build your UI based on the current state. [`The BLoC pattern`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) is especially good for this sort of approach.